# Creating a utillity class which extends activity

Tags: java, android

When developing an app, i came across many times when i needed to perform some action (that requires context to be of type Activity) from inside a class which dont extend Activity.

For example: create an AlarmManager event, creating a broadcast or manipulating System Services.

Is it a good idea to create a static activity which will function as a utillity class to perform actions?

The benefit will be that it will be available for access from the entire app classes.

Otherwiswe i find my self duplicating code from one activity to another.

Comment: creating a utility class is always a good idea. Why are you confused?

Comment: If your utility class needs a context pass one to it in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static MyApplication instance = new MyApplication();
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

}
```

You can call this by simply `MyApplication.getContext();`

And add this tag into your AndroidManifest.xml to initialize this class when your application get started.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="com.example.application.MyApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Take this as a constructive critic: you should add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: What is the point of overriding getApplicationContext and doing nothing? and what is the point of static instance that isn't using? You need to also show how to reference this in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: sorry guyz it was little mistake you need to call MyApplication.getContext() to get the context within your application.

Comment: @GregEnnis - getApplicationContext() method is needed to be override within your class because you need to initialize the Application Class & getApplicationContext() will call to it's super class method. Otherwise u'll need to initialize implicitly.

Comment: @GregEnnis - Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's <application> tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure these calls need an `Activity` and not a `Context`. I believe the cases you mention only require a `Context`, which is readily available outside of an Activity. For example, an Android `Service` derives from Context, as does the `Application` object itself.